# Align vertex data

Tags: ios, opengl, opengl-es-2.0

I've read [this post](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData/TechniquesforWorkingwithVertexData.html) about vertex alignement and I'm not sure to understand everything.

The article say that I need to add an offset after each attributs to have aligned data (By the way, the article talk about 4 bytes but in his picture, they add two bytes).

In my situation, I've got something like that:

```
Position : 3 floats         (3 * 4 bytes = 12)
Colors   : 4 unsigned char  (4 * 1 bytes = 4)
Uvs      : 2 shorts         (2 * 2 bytes = 4)
```

So, I've just to add 4 bytes for each attributs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article recommends 4-byte alignment per attribute. In the example, they use an attribute with 3 Shorts is used, which is 6 byte total, so the follwoing attribute will not be aligned to 4-byte-boundaries. Hence, they add two padding bytes.

In your case, all attributes are multiples of 4 bytes already, so you don't habe to add any padding to get 4-byte alignment.